# Migrating from SQL Server to firebird: pro and cons

Tags: sql-server, migration, sql-server-express, firebird

I am considering the migration for 4 reasons:

1) SQLSERVER installation is a nightmare, expecially for 1-user software (Even if typically I have 3-20 users, sometimes I sell my software to single users: it is incredible to have troubles installing the DB, while installing the applicatino means copying an exe...). (note my max installation is 100 users, but there is no an upper limit). Software installs in 10 seconds, SQLServer in 1 hour. Firebird installation is much easier.

2) SQLSERVER runs on windows server only

3) My customers have all the express edition

4) i am not using any advanced feature, I am now starting using filestream, but the main reason for this is that Express edition has 4/10GB db size limit

So these are all Pros of moving to Firebird.

Which are the cons?

I can also plan to support both platforms, but this will backfire I fear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any besides need to thoroughly test all of your existing code for compatability issues.

Comment: Ok, the obvious Cons is that the migration of the DB is not for free. Anyway after this step it is done probably yuo are right: there are no Cons.

Answer (score 4):

MSSQL server is faster and better optimized for large databases and complex queries, especially if administered properly, while Firebird alows you to run without any administration and just forget about it. Although this penalty affects very small percentage of people using it, before complete migration I suggest you to first just migrate data and then test speed of most complex query on both systems. If speed satisfies you then you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the adivce, I postponed the migration for now. At present I am closer to Postgres as an alternative since it has an higher compatibility with sql server in my particular case (=less work to do to migrate).

Answer (score 2):

Firebird is wonderful for server installations or single user installations.

It has an embedded version that is suitable for single user scenarios and you do not have to install anything.

It uses the same database file for both server and embedded database so you can easy go from single user to multi user and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

I have embedded Firebird 2.5 today in my freeware Software. It's great, and there had never been connection problems. I used multiple processes to do both insert and read long operations simultaneously and it all gone correct as was expected. I am waiting for Firebird 3.0. I recommend Firebird when you don't want to trust on other commercial database software.

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one user you can use Sqlite which is even easier to manage than Firebird.

Comment: No, there can be any number of users. But typical value is 3-20. I edited the question to specify this better.